# Recursion, inner loop and time complexity

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Consider the following function:

```
int testFunc(int n){
    if(n < 3) return 0;
    int num = 7;
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j *= 2) num++;
    for(int k = n; k > 1; k--) num++;
    return testFunc(n/3) + num;
}
```

I get that the first loop is O(logn) while the second loop gives O(n) which gives a time complexity of O(n) in total. But due to the recursive calls I thought the time complexity would be **O(nlogn)**, but apperantly it is only **O(n)**. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive call pretty much gives the following for the complexity(denoting the complexity for input n by `T(n)`):

```
T(n) = log(n) + n + T(n/3)
```

First observation as you correctly noted is that you can ignore the logarithm as it is dominated by `n`. Now we are only left with `T(n) = n + T(n/3)`. Try writing this up to 0 for instance. We have:

```
T(n) = n + n/3 + n/9+....
```

You can easily prove that the above sum is always less than `2*n`. In fact better limits can be proven but this one is enough to state that overall complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Much simpler to comprehend than the Master theorem, IMO. Also, the sum is also less than `1.5*n`.

Comment: Ahh I see. It's a geometric progression. Nice explained

Comment: @novalain yes and the value 1.5 that JohnBupit mentions is the tightest bound possible precisely because of the sum of the geometric regression

Answer (score 1):

For procedures using a recursive algorithm such as the following:

```
procedure T( n : size of problem ) defined as:
     if n < base_case then exit

     Do work of amount f(n) // In this case, the O(n) for loop

     T(n/b)
     T(n/b)
     ... a times... // In this case, b = 3, and a = 1
     T(n/b)
end procedure
```

Applying the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to find the time complexity, the `f(n)` in this case is `O(n)` (due to the second for loop, like you said). This makes `c = 1`.

Now, log<sub>b</sub>a = log<sub>3</sub>1 = 0, making this the **3rd case** of the theorem, according to which the time complexity `T(n) = Θ(f(n)) = Θ(n)`.

Comment: By masters theorem,`T(n) = a*T(n/b)+f(n)`. Replacing with values for a,b,and `f(n)` with 1,3, and we know that `f(n) = n+log(n)` => `f(n) =n` (just like @john-bupit answer). we get `T(n) = 1*T(n/3)+n` => `T(n) = T(n/3)+n`. Now look at the answer of @Ivaylo-strandjev . Like he said this will be equal to `T(n) = n + n/3 + n/9+ ...` => `O(n)`. Hope this helps. And thank you guys. Even I was not able to answer But by comparing the answer It helped me and I should thank you guys for that.